# Polymer build does not output images folder?

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli, polymer-app-toolbox

I am following the [Build an app with App Toolbox](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up) tutorial. In the Step 4 (Deploy), after calling `polymer build` command, the `build/bundled` and `build/unbundled` folder are created, but there are no images folder in them. This causes the tab icon not to show up when I deployed the build.

Here are some screenshots:-

In localhost development, the tab icon shows up:

[image]

I deployed the build to firebase (https://polymer-app-toolbox.firebaseapp.com/), there is no app-icon because images folder is not in the build output:

[image]

Am I missing something? Anyone else seeing the same problem?